# Android studio 2.3.1 Error converting bytecode to dex

Tags: android, gradle

I had just added this dependency(compile 'com.google.guava:guava:21.0') to the gradle and when I try to run the app I get the error below.I tried cleaning the project, but it didn't help me.Can somebody please help me with a solution

Error:

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add 
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
to that submodule's build.gradle file.
Error:1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pre-dex 'C:\Users\Zabit\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.guava\guava\21.0\3a3d111be1be1b745edfa7d91678a12d7ed38709\guava-21.0.jar' to 'E:\Ohxee\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\debug\folders\1000\10\guava-21.0_c8c319a8080e46e7bfc8243fe4c3e3b2a6150f16'
```

build.gradle(app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.xxxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true

        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.borax12.materialdaterangepicker:library:1.9'
    compile 'com.iceteck.silicompressorr:silicompressor:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.patrickpissurno:ripple-effect:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.4.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.darsh2:MultipleImageSelect:3474549'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:21.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'


}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the Guava/Java version. From Guava version 21 and up the requirement is Java 8 according to the [documentation](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Compatibility).

Android Studio (and Android to this point) are still on JDK 7 with some of JDK 8 features. Thankfully they provide a Guava flavor for that according to [this](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UseGuavaInYourBuild).

Basically all you have to do is:

```
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:22.0-android'
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

First **Clean** the project

Than try **Make Project**

Now **Run** the project module

Comment: If you have the project with sub module, Can you add this

 compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
and try inside your build.gradle(project/module)

Comment: I added that now I got this erorr    Error:(23, 0) Could not find method compileOptions() for arguments [build_58jzqqrivbdfgfchs104vwi47$_run_closure2@3c095506] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
<a href="openFile:E:\Ohxee\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: http://prntscr.com/f4t7ha this is the way to add compatibilities, Add targetCompatibility, sourceCompatibility to your modules

Comment: Still does not help me

Comment: Ok.Tell me this.Is there any class in Java that allows duplicate keys to be added.Hashmap doesnot allow it.